# Swift - Pass multiple arguments in whereField clause to retrieve from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to swift and trying to do some basic operations.
 My scenarios here is, i am trying to fetch data from firebase by passing arguments as a search criteria. For example i am looking for a blood donors in my database filtered out by blood group and city, i need to pass two arguments as my search criteria. But in a whereField method i can only pass one argument. Is there a way or another method that i can use to pass multiple arguments?

below is the code that i have till now

```
@IBAction func fetchDataButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("users").whereField("bloodgroup", isEqualTo: "A-").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error == nil && snapshot != nil {

            self.resultArray.removeAll()
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let dict = document.data()
                let x = dict["firstname"] as? String

                self.resultArray.append(x!)
                    self.myTableView.dataSource = self

                    self.myTableView.reloadData()



            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To filter on both blood type and city, you can just add multiple calls to `whereField(` to the question. So for example:

```
db.collection("users")
  .whereField("bloodgroup", isEqualTo: "A-")
  .whereField("city", isEqualTo: "Chicago")
  .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
```

If you want to filter for multiple blood types, you can use the (quite new) [`in` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any):

```
db.collection("users")
  .whereField("bloodgroup", in: ["A-", "A+"])
  .whereField("city", isEqualTo: "Chicago")
  .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
```